# Get text of dropped div from another browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, droppable

I'm trying to make script that will alloow user drag and drop  from one browser tab to another.
Basic idea is simple - on one page of site I have list of stock tickers, and on another web page there is a chart. When user drags div with ticker to chart I want to reload chart.

I've created divs on first page:

```
<div draggable="true">GOOG</div>
<div draggable="true">APPL</div>
```

And I've set up 'drop' event listener on another page:

```
$('#chart').bind("dragover", false)
    .bind("dragenter", false)
    .bind("drop", function(e) {

      console.log(e.dataTransfer); //undefined!
      console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer); //empty object with no files, items or types!


    return false;
});
```

**The problem is that there is NO info about div that was being dragged in Event object.** 
It works great with images and files but doen't want to work with simple DIV. Any help?